# Control the structure of a nested list when apply FUN returns list or NA

Tags: r, list, nested, apply

I have a vector `v` and matrix `m` and use apply to extract a subset of results from `cor.test` function (correlations between `v` and `m` columns).

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(runif(12), nrow = 3) 
v <- 3:1

res <- apply(m, 2, function(x) {
  cor.test(x, v, method = 'spearman', exact = F)[c(1,3,4)]
})
```

This is a nested list of list with length equal to the number of columns in `m` - and in the structure I would like as output (2-level list).

```
> str(res)
List of 4
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ statistic: Named num 8
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  ..$ p.value  : num 0
  ..$ estimate : Named num -1
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ statistic: Named num 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  ..$ p.value  : num 0.667
  ..$ estimate : Named num 0.5
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ statistic: Named num 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  ..$ p.value  : num 0
  ..$ estimate : Named num 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ statistic: Named num 6
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  ..$ p.value  : num 0.667
  ..$ estimate : Named num -0.5
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
```

I want to filter each `cor.test` result, say the p.value, within the apply loop and return NA to indicate filtered results (retaining the length of the result, here four).

```
res <- apply(m, 2, function(x) {
  tmp <- cor.test(x, v, method = 'spearman', exact = F)[c(1,3,4)]
  ifelse(tmp$p.value < 0.1, list(tmp), NA)
})
```

My problem is that we now get a 3-level list structure

```
res2 <- apply(m, 2, function(x) {
  tmp <- cor.test(x, v, method = 'spearman', exact = F)[c(1,3,4)]
  ifelse(tmp$p.value < 0.1, list(tmp), NA)
  })

> str(res2)
List of 4
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ statistic: Named num 8
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  .. ..$ p.value  : num 0
  .. ..$ estimate : Named num -1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ : logi NA
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ statistic: Named num 0
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  .. ..$ p.value  : num 0
  .. ..$ estimate : Named num 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ : logi NA
```

Only if the first result from `apply` is NA the result structure is like desired, obviously since `apply` then can fit unfiltered result to the structure.

```
res3 <- apply(m, 2, function(x) {
  tmp <- cor.test(x, v, method = 'spearman', exact = F)[c(1,3,4)]
  ifelse(tmp$p.value > 0.1, list(tmp), NA) #'invert' the test
})

>res3
List of 4
 $ : logi NA
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ statistic: Named num 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  ..$ p.value  : num 0.667
  ..$ estimate : Named num 0.5
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ : logi NA
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ statistic: Named num 6
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  ..$ p.value  : num 0.667
  ..$ estimate : Named num -0.5
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
```

I have tried to return `ifelse(tmp$p.value < 0.1, tmp, NA)` and `ifelse(tmp$p.value < 0.1, list(tmp), list(NA))` in vain.

The only solution I found is to assign `NA` outside the `apply`:

```
res4 <- apply(m, 2, function(x) {
  cor.test(x, v, method = 'spearman', exact = F)[c(1,3,4)]
})
res4[sapply(res4, "[[", 2) > 0.1] <- NA
```

Clearly, I miss something about the inner workings of apply.

Comment: I would highly recommend looking at the `broom` package to simplify the results into a tidy data frame prior to extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue isn't with `apply` but with `ifelse`. If you use `if () {} else {}` instead, it works the way you intend

```
res3 <- apply(m, 2, function(x) {
      tmp <- cor.test(x, v, method = 'spearman', exact = F)[c(1,3,4)]
      if (tmp$p.value < 0.1) { return(tmp) } else { return(NA) }
  })

str(res3)
# List of 4
 # $ :List of 3
  # ..$ statistic: Named num 8
  # .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  # ..$ p.value  : num 0
  # ..$ estimate : Named num -1
  # .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 # $ : logi NA
 # $ :List of 3
  # ..$ statistic: Named num 0
  # .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
  # ..$ p.value  : num 0
  # ..$ estimate : Named num 1
  # .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 # $ : logi NA
```

Note documentation from `ifelse`

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test

Comment: I think your quote is not the best way to illustrate the issue. Try `ifelse(FALSE, list(list(a = 1, b = 2)), NA)` and `ifelse(TRUE, list(list(a = 1, b = 2)), NA)`. Rather I would say the issue that you have to return `list(list(...))` with `ifelse`.

Comment: `shape`, which isn't my word choice, is ambiguous here...of course what you say is right. You have to return `list(list(...))`. But as I understand it, that's because `test` is 1-element, and as a result `return(tmp)` will only return the first element of the output (i.e. first element of the list). Since OP wants to keep the entire list, OP must return `list(list(...))` with `ifelse`, which is why `if (condition) {} else {}` works because it does not impose a *shape* to the output.

Comment: I agree! An also find your solution to be good. It was not clear to what you meant by  _Note documentation from `ifelse` ..._